# Backpacking in Pärnu in the summer

Tags: accommodation, backpacking, hostels, estonia

Are there any (backpacker) hostels in [Pärnu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A4rnu), the "summer capital" of Estonia? If not, how about cozy B&Bs or guesthouses... or well, anything other than big hotel / spa complexes?

I'm more interested in the social vibe etc of backpacker places rather than solely budget lodging, but while at it, does anyone know what's the general price level for a room/bed in Pärnu (budget / midrange; nothing fancy)?

Wikitravel is not very generous when it comes to [Pärnu accommodation](http://wikitravel.org/en/P%C3%A4rnu#Sleep). But there should be *something* for backpackers in the city, [according to sites like visitestonia.com](http://www.visitestonia.com/en/holiday-destinations/city-guides/parnu) anyways... :-)

> Pärnu has something for everybody - families, backpackers, youngsters,
>   romantic couples, sports enthusiasts, people interested in culture and
>   art - you name it! There’s always a reason to revisit Pärnu.

Also, at the height of the summer, can you generally find any place to stay in Pärnu without reserving a long time beforehand?

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is!

[Hostelbookers](http://www.hostelbookers.com/)  currently lists three properties for Parnu.  A hostel, a guesthouse and a motel.

Surprisingly (they normally overlap), [Hostelworld](http://www.hostelworld.com/search?search_keywords=Parnu,%20Estonia&country=Estonia&city=Parnu) has three **different** properties - a guesthouse, campsite and hostel.

Hopefully some of those appeal, although they don't appear terribly big, so it'd pay to book in advance.  Hostelbookers also appears to have a summer sale on at present.